# p5.js // p5.vector.sub how it works and what it does exactly2

Tags: javascript, java, p5.js

I'm watching a new tutorial video of P5.js.

I was following until I saw him calling a static function `P5.VECTOR.SUB(...)`.

I couldn't understand what he is doing here, can someone explain please

Thanks

[image: video tutorial screenshot]

Comment: Check [this](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/sub).

Answer (score 1):

Questions like this are best answered by [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

That page links to the reference page for [p5.Vector](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) which then links to the reference page for [p5.Vector.sub()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/sub).

That page explains what's going on, emphasis mine:

> Subtracts x, y, and z components from a vector, subtracts one vector from another, or subtracts two independent vectors. **The version of the method that subtracts two vectors is a static method and returns a p5.Vector**, the other acts directly on the vector. See the examples for more context.

It also contains a code sample:

```
// Static method
var v1 = createVector(2, 3, 4);
var v2 = createVector(1, 2, 3);

var v3 = p5.Vector.sub(v1, v2);
// v3 has components [1, 1, 1]
print(v3);
```

I'd also encourage you to put together a little example program that tests what's going on, instead of trying to understand it in a larger program.

Answer (score 0):

In the tuto, it calculates the vector from begin to end by subsracting the positions.
Think about as an arrow going from begin to end, so giving a direction.
Using the static version of sub is done to protect original values.